# Updating Text In XML File

Tags: powershell

I have the following xml file.

```
<Objects>
  <Object>
    <Property Name="Browser">Firefox</Property>
    <Property Name="PDF">Adobe Reader</Property>
</Object>
```

I want to be able to update the word firefox using powershell script.

This is the powershell script that am working and is not working.

```
$xmlDoc = [XML](Get-Content "c:\Windows\personalsettings\PersonalSettings.xml")
 foreach ($item in  $xmlDoc.Objects.Object.Property)
 {
    $item.Name = 'Chrome'
 }
 $xmlDoc.Save("c:\Windows\personalsettings\PersonalSettings.xml")
```

Comment: Can you provide with an example using my data?

Answer (score 0):

```
[xml]$XML = @"
<Objects>
  <Object>
    <Property Name="Browser">Firefox</Property>
    <Property Name="PDF">Adobe Reader</Property>
  </Object>
</Objects>
"@

$XML.SelectSingleNode('//Property[@Name="Browser"]')
$XML.SelectSingleNode('//Property[@Name="Browser"]').InnerText = "TEST"
$XML.SelectSingleNode('//Property[@Name="Browser"]')
```

Results will be

```
> Name    #text  
> ----    ----- 
> Browser Firefox
> Browser TEST
```

What you are looking for is **XPATH**

Works like this

> //Path Or NodeName[@AttributeName="Value Of Attribute"]

Once you get the Node you can then edit that node how you see fit.

Comment: Thanks for the example. However, when running your code is replace the word browser with the new text instead of replacing the value after the word browser.

Comment: No its not. In my example it would be impossible for it to change the word browser.
Make sure you are changing the `InnerText`

Comment: $xmlDoc = [XML](Get-Content "c:\Windows\personalsettings\PersonalSettings.xml")

$XML.SelectSingleNode('//Property[@Name="Browser"]').InnerText = "TEST"

$xmlDoc.Save("c:\Windows\personalsettings\PersonalSettings.xml")
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:3 char:1
+ $XML.SelectSingleNode('//Property[@Name="Browser"]').InnerText = "TES ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: If you look at the example you gave... you didnt really have real XML. you forgot to end the example with a `</Objects>` Meaning that there is no `//Property[@Name="Browser"]` because you did not have finished XML.

Comment: Again, here is the xml file:

<Objects>
  <Object>
    <Property Name="Browser">Firefox</Property>
    <Property Name="PDF">Adobe Reader</Property>
  </Object>
</Objects>

Comment: Your calling your xml `$xmlDoc` but when you do the XPATH you are using `$XML`. `$XML` is null you need to call the xpath on `$XMLDOC`. `$XMLDOC.SelectSingleNode('//Property[@Name="Browser"]').InnerText = "TEST"`

Comment: That was it. Thanks Thanks so much! On a side note, do you know why every time the code runs, there is a strange message poping out saying "object not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Thats not enough information to help you. I mean I would need to see code and stuff. Did you make a post? if so whats the Post. If not make one so i can look.

Comment: it is working now. Thanks